# Change background color of ImageView

Tags: android, kotlin, picasso

I load image into ImageView by using Picasso.

But problem is, when I load the image, it has a white background and my application background has another color. I want to transform the white color of the image I load to the primary color of my application.

This is my code but it doesn't work, I can't guess why.

```
picasso.load(data[i].image)//download URL
        .fit()
        .centerInside()
        .error(R.drawable.com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait)//if failed
        .into(viewHolder.image)
viewHolder.image?.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, R.color.colorPrimary, null))
```

This is my xml :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:src="@drawable/com_facebook_profile_picture_blank_portrait"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/inventory_item_guideline"/>
```

[image]

I want to change the white background to my primary color one.

Comment: Remove `null` . Try with `viewHolder.image?.setBackgroundColor(ResourcesCompat.getColor(context.resources, R.color.colorPrimary))` and Check Your IMAGE

Answer (score -1):

you need to use **placeholder** to show any image or color before image loads.

```
.placeholder(R.color.colorPrimary)
```

Comment: It isn't my problem.actually, I want to transform the white background of the picture to another color.

Comment: What do you mean by Transform? Is it like when the image loads in imageView then white changes to some other color?

Comment: If you want to transform white color to your colorPrimary then why you loading white image from network via picasso? just set src of ImageView to colorPrimary

Comment: @anandwana001 No, I want to make the white bakckground color of my image to my primary color one. I edited my question.

Comment: are your images png (without any background)? DId you check your image width and height? if your image cover whole imageView then you cannot show primary color!

Comment: @anandwana001 is right, please check your images are not transparent. Your images having white background.